# Difference between who are you? & who you are

Tags: american-english, british-english

I am in confused that When I ask to unknown person, then how to ask: Who are you? or Who you are..

Other examples:
What is he doing? or what he is doing..
How are you? or how you are..

What is the reason behind that? In which condition we use them separately ?

Comment: "Who you are" isn't a question.  Or even a complete sentence.

Answer (score 2):

> Who are you?

The above is a question.  It employs an inverted structure so that the listener knows it's a question.  By "inverted structure," I mean that it places the primary subject of the noun "are" after the verb.  Uninverted, it would be: "You are who?"  "Who" appears in the question—no matter how it's stated—as a second subject, as part of the predicate, specifically the predicate nominative.

> who you are

The above is a clause, always appearing as all or part of a noun clause.  As such, it only appears as part of a larger sentence, for example:

- It depends on who you are.
- I don't know who you are anymore!
- You want to know who you are?  Who you are is the love of my life.
- Who you are to everyone else doesn't matter to me because it's not who you are to me.